# Git - Enforcing Pull Embargos

Tags: git, workflow

I was wondering if there was a way to enforce pull embargos (no pulling on X branch until further notice, happens when things go wrong) in Git by default or if that is something the team will have to create through pre-pull hooks and commands.

Quick example of what I mean:

> -User A pushes a change that works on his computer due to development.
>
> -User B/Server notices that the recent pull has broken down for him and calls an embargo.
>
> -User A & B start working on the issue.
>
> -In the meantime, User C wants to pull recent changes. The embargo should stop him from doing so to avoid breaking the build for him and stop him from working.

Answer (score 1):

Before I get to a direct answer, I would point some things out:

First, the premise that a bad pull would stop a developer from working is false.  Worst case a developer can check out the previous state.  If they don't want to be in detached head state, they can even use `reset` to make their refs fall back to a previous state, making them no worse off than with your "embargo" idea.  At most it should be an inconvenience.

Second, this is not something I can remember ever running into.  If you are running into it often, I'd suggest you improve your policies on branching, testing, and merging to make it a rare case that a shared branch is put in a broken state.

For example, if development is done on feature branches, then a feature is tested by merging the shared branch onto the feature and loading the result into a test environment, and only on passage of testing is the feature merged back to the shared branch... then there is very little chance for the scenario you outlined to occur.

With the issue reduced to a rare inconvenience, it seems unlikely that it's worth going through extra hoops to create procedures that limit your developers rather than just giving them the information they need to make good decisions about how to proceed.

But perhaps you find all that unconvincing.  So...

There is not default functionality for this.

You could try to use hooks.  But what hook would you use, and what would it do?  If you really want to *prevent* a pull, you need a server-side hook to actually prevent a fetch (because once the objects are in the clone repo there's nothing you can do about the user moving their refs around), and if you prevent a fetch then nobody can pull *anything*.  I know of no way to do that anyway.

If you recognize this as a convenience for the developer (rather than a policy to be enforced), then you could try to set up some combination of client-side hooks instead... but I still can't see any way to piece them together to do what you want done.  (Plus your client-side hooks would have to consult some central list, or else they'd have to be updated every time you impose or lift an "embargo".  At best this cuts into git's advantages for offline operation, and it just seems like a lot of complexity to insert into what should be routine operations.

The closest thing you could maybe do is, when you spot the problem, reset the branch ref on the remote to before the bad commit.  This is effective a rebase of published commits, though, and can cause the developers as much (or more) inconvenience as you're trying to prevent in the first place.

So my advice keeps coming back to the same point: This is not a good idea.  A better idea is to communicate with your team so that they can be warned "if you pull this branch right now, it will break your build".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking to push this out of the "gentlemen agreement" and into enforced territory but looking at your response, we will be examining other paths to do so before we commit to anything specific and see what is the most cost efficient.